# How to get aggregations and sort based on child document hits in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

I have documents indexed like so:

```
{
  "attrib": "value", // etc
  "prices": [
    {
      "p": 10,
      "d": "2016-01-01"
    },
    {
      "p": 20,
      "d": "2016-01-02"
    },
    {
      "p": 30,
      "d": "2016-01-03"
    },
    {
      "p": 40,
      "d": "2016-01-04"
    }
  ]
}
```

I would like to get aggregation buckets to tell me something like this:

Price Buckets

- `prices.p` between 1 and 10 (20)
- `prices.p` between 11 and 20 (22)
- `prices.p` between 21 and 30 (2)

Date Buckets

- `prices.d` between Jan 1 and Jan 30 (20)
- `prices.d` between Feb 1 and Feb 28 (22)
- `prices.d` between Mar 1 and Mar 30 (2)

Where the count would show the number of parent documents that have `prices.X` between X and Y, NOT the number of prices in total.

Secondary to this, if I wanted to perform a filter to only get documents with `prices.p` between 1 and 30, I'd need the aggregation to reflect this.

Thirdly, I'd like to be able to order my results by the top child hit of the result.

So in plain English, my query would be:

*"Find me all documents with at least one price between X and Y having a date between A and B, order the results by price (or date as required)"*

My query so far:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "prices.p": {
                            "gte": 1,
                            "lte": 30
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "path": "prices",
                "inner_hits": {
                  "sort": [
                    "p"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This returns documents in the default sort order, but with the `inner_hits` sorted by `prices.p` - so then I can display the lowest price for an item, alongwith the date for that price (`prices.d`).

Similarly, I'd like to be able to filter where `prices.d` is between two dates - also aggregating the dates.

Lastly, I'd like to be able to order my full document hits by the first inner hit (`p` or `d`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use nested aggregations. To build two buckets, you have to run two parallel nested aggregations.

To filter furthur more your bucket, you can add a parent query which will filter your document set as well as your buckets.

Following is the query, I changed nested d type to integer for my simplicity, but this will work for you on date range as well.

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "p_range": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "prices"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "p_nested_range": {
          "range": {
            "field": "prices.p",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": 0,
                "to": 1000
              },
              {
                "from": 1000,
                "to": 2000
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "d_range" :{
      "nested": {
        "path": "prices"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "d_nested_range": {
          "range": {
            "field": "prices.d",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": 0,
                "to": 500
              },
              {
                "from": 500,
                "to": 1000
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "prices.p": {
                            "gte": 200,
                            "lte": 1400
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "path": "prices",
                "inner_hits": {
                  "sort": [
                    "prices.p"
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Furthur more if you want to filter only document sets, but you don't want your query to effect your buckets, you can take a look at [post_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html)

Edit - To sort parent document based on first inner_hit inside prices nested type, use the following query.
You don't need to have a sort clause inside innerhits, as sort inside innerhits is used to sort the nested type only not the parent doc

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "p_range": {
      "nested": {
        "path": "prices"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "p_nested_range": {
          "range": {
            "field": "prices.p",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": 0,
                "to": 1000
              },
              {
                "from": 1000,
                "to": 2000
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "d_range" :{
      "nested": {
        "path": "prices"
      },
      "aggs": {
        "d_nested_range": {
          "range": {
            "field": "prices.d",
            "ranges": [
              {
                "from": 0,
                "to": 500
              },
              {
                "from": 500,
                "to": 1000
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "nested": {
                "filter": {
                  "bool": {
                    "must": [
                      {
                        "range": {
                          "prices.p": {
                            "gte": 200,
                            "lte": 1400
                          }
                        }
                      }
                    ]
                  }
                },
                "path": "prices",
                "inner_hits": {

                }
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "query": {
        "match_all": {}
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": {
        "_script" : {
            "type" : "number",
            "script" : {

                "inline": "_source.prices[0].p"

            },
            "order" : "asc"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: sure, can you explain this "Lastly, I'd like to be able to order my full document hits by the first inner hit (p or d)"

Comment: i have edited the query for sorting parent doc based on first hit inside nested prices doc